# eliminate trigonometric terms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Consider the following simultaneous equations.
$$
\begin{align}
& 2\beta^3\cos(3\omega\tau) = 1+3\alpha^2-\alpha^3-3\alpha+3(\alpha-1)\omega^2+3(\alpha-1)\beta^2\cos(2\omega\tau)-3\beta^2\omega\sin(2\omega\tau)\\\\
& 2\beta^3\sin(3\omega\tau) = \omega^3+3(2\alpha-1-\alpha^2)\omega
+3\beta^2\omega\cos(2\omega\tau)+3(\alpha-1)\beta^2\sin(2\omega\tau)
\end{align}
$$
where $\alpha,~\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau, \omega>0$. My wish is to eliminate all the trigonometric terms by squaring and then summing both sides of the equations. To do this, I have used computer algebra systems such as Maple or Mathematica. Unfortunately, what I get still has trigonometric terms, and I have no clue how to get rid of them! The final expression is of the form
$$
A\sin(\omega\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)+B\cos^2(\omega\tau)=C\;,
$$
where $A,~B,~C$ are expressions involving only $\alpha,\beta$, and $\omega$. I am soliciting for ideas on how best to get rid of the trigonometric terms in the above expression. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what your "end game" is, but let's see if this helps:

From this (assuming this is correct): $A\sin(\omega\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)+B\cos^2(\omega\tau)=C$

You can then go to $\frac{A}{2}\sin(2\omega\tau) + \frac{B}{2}[\cos(2\omega\tau) + 1] = C$

You can then rearrange that into the form $A'\sin(2\omega\tau) + B'\cos(2\omega\tau) = C'$

Now you can express that as $\sqrt{A'^2 + B'^2}{\sin(2\omega\tau + \arctan(\frac{B'}{A'}))} = C'$

That should allow you to solve for $\omega\tau$ in terms of the other variables.

Is that what you want to do?

Comment: No, this is not what I want. I would like to end up with a polynomial in powers of $\omega$. That is my "end game", to borrow your terminology.

Comment: @Math_Life In which case, I doubt very much that anything you do is going to be successful. Sine and Cosine are transcendental functions that cannot be expressed as (finite) polynomials of their arguments. You can, of course, find an infinite series in terms of the argument and the coefficients, but it'll be messy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your last expression is correct $$A\sin(\omega\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)+B\cos^2(\omega\tau)=C$$ you have two possibilities. The first is in Deepak's answer : rewrite the expression using the double angle and get $$A\sin(2\omega\tau)+B\cos(2\omega\tau)=2C-1$$ So now, you face the classic trigonometric equation you could solve using the traditional methods; it will lead to complicated but manageable expressions.

To simplify the solution, you can also use Weierstrass and set $t=\tan(\omega \tau)$. After simplification, the last formula will then write $$ (B+2 C-1)t^2-2 A t-(B-2 C+1)=0$$ the solutions of which being $$t_{\pm}=\frac{A\pm\sqrt{A^2+B^2-4 C^2+4 C-1}}{B+2 C-1}$$